# How to run multiple exes with giving admin privileges at single time

Tags: windows-xp, administrator

I want to run multiple exe's more than 300 at single time, this apps need admin privileges so they ask me to give admin privileges each time is there any way give them admin access single time.

Comment: Disable User Account Control prompt from control panel. Then make a batch file with all the .exe full path and run .bat as admin.

Comment: Start one cmd with admin privileges. Every application you start from within that cmd shouldn't ask for those privileges.